# Software for simulating/calculating a known EMW pulse propagating in ISM, including dispersion, scattering, etc

Tags: observational-astronomy, radio-astronomy, interstellar-medium, radio-telescope

Could you please let me know, if there is any software/code/tool for simulating/calculating the result of a short EMW pulse (waveform is exactly known) propagating in the ISM for long distance, including effects of especially the dispersion, scattering, etc?

Comment: There are plenty, but they're all dedicated to a particular part of the spectrum / particular physical processes. It will be easier to guide you if you could write more specifically what your purpose is, e.g. are you interested in how starlight is absorbed/scattered by gas and/or dust, how UV ionizes the neutral gas, how Lyman alpha scatters its way through the ISM, etc? Are you interested in idealized model galaxies, hydrodynamically simulated galaxies, or just molecular clouds?

Comment: @pela Thank you very much. Simply, if a short EM pulse (planar wave, pulse duration is ms level, time-domain waveform is known, freq band is e.g. MHz to 10MHz, or higher) propagates from somewhere in the Milky way (within disk) to the Earth, through the ISM, I hope to calculate/obtain the concrete waveform of this EM wave when it arrives at the Earth, considering some dominating effects such as dispersion, scattering, absorbing caused by the ISM.  I understand that the actual situation would be complicated, but once the algorithm covers the major contribution it will be good enough. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, radiative transfer in the radio regime is far from my expertise, so I don't think I can be of any help. There's a code called [ASTRORAY](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014ascl.soft07007S) that does RT of (polarized) radio/sub-mm near black holes that you may be able to modify to your needs?

Comment: @pela Thank you very much. I will try the ASTRORAY.